# Cytoscape- Adding node attributes during import from table

Tags: cytoscape

In cytoscape is there a way to import node attributes while importing network from table. It clearly states columns in blue will be loaded as edge attributes, but nothing corresponding to node attribute is mentioned.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely.  Upgrade to a more recent version of Cytoscape (3.5 is the current version) and you'll see that the import network dialog now allows you to choose columns to use for source nodes, source node attributes, target nodes, target node attributes, and edge attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I am still on version 3.0.2